# MediaWiki Login page restriction from specific IP address

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mediawiki

Have an MediaWiki page, that provide an information about some software and products. Is not used for discussions, and only one admin can create pages. I prevent users to create own accounts, and is working fine.
As a bit of higher level of security, I will like to restrict login to admin panel from just one specific IP address.
For WordPress, I do it in Apache2 at next way:

```
<Directory "/opt/htdocs/www.xxxx.xxx/wp-admin">
                Require all denied
                Require ip a.b.c.d
                Require ip e.f.g.h
</Directory>
```

How can I do the same, but with MediaWiki?

Comment: "...but with MediaWiki?" - Potentially the same way. The method you posted is not specific to WordPress. What URL(s) are requested in order to login to the admin panel on MediaWiki?

Comment: @MrWhite
The problem is the URL because it uses index.php to serve the other content. The exact login URL is: 
`https://wiki.xxxx.xxx/w/index.php?title=Special:UserLogin&returnto=Main+Page`